# How to open and close an executable inside a loop in python

Tags: python, subprocess

Python noob here , I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question.

So , I wrote this code

```
import subprocess
import os, signal
import time
timeout = time.time() + 60*5
count = 0

while True:
    print("running")
    if time.time() > timeout:
        break
    
    speedtest = subprocess.Popen("C:\Program Files\Speedtest\Speedtest.exe")
    time.sleep(30.0)
    speedtest.terminate()
```

I`m trying to open speedtest.exe, keep it open for 30 seconds and close it. I want to keep repeating this for 5 minutes.

But when the process closes for the first time and tries to reopen , I get an error saying another instance is already running.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Try sleeping a little bit right after you call `.terminate()`

Comment: @12944qwerty It worked  , thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to sleep a little bit after terminating the executable. This is because terminating takes a bit of time, and unfortunately, the terminate method doesn't take all that time when compiling. It goes directly from mid-termination to starting the exe again.
By waiting, you're waiting for the executable to stop and then start the application. You will have to mess with the timings a bit though since there will generally be a random amount of time for termination.